# Identifying a quotient group (NBHM-$2014$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\mathbb C^*$ denote the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers and let $P$ denote the subgroup of positive real numbers. Identify the quotient group.

My thought $$\frac{\mathbb C^*}{P}=\{P,-P,iP,-iP\}.$$ Is it right?

Comment: Which of those 4 cosets contains a complex cube root of 1?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $P$ contains $1$..

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I do not understand your idea.... :O could you please explain a bit more...

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam : why do you think the quotient group is same as what you have written... it would be better if you can try writing that partially...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Partially?? I am not even sure about the correctness of what I have written..

Comment: I know that if you are sure of the correctness you would not ask :D.. I am asking for your intuition....

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam:  Is `... positive real numbers...` above the same as $\mathbb R^*_{>0}$?

Comment: @B.S... yes definitely

Comment: I guess Gerry is thinking that if none of these four cosets contains a complex cube root of $1$ then the conjectured solution cannot be corret.

Comment: The quotient essentially collapses each open ray from 0 to a point. There is one such ray for each direction from 0. Can you visualize the resulting quotient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can set this map $$f:\mathbb C^*\to U,~~z=a+ib\mapsto \frac{a}{|z|}+i\frac{b}{|z|}$$ wherein $U=\{z\in\mathbb C^*\mid|z|=1\}$. Show this map is surjective with $\ker f=\mathbb R^*_{>0}$.

Comment: For short: $f(z)=z/|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

One another way,

The map $f:\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$ defined by $f(z=r.e^{i\theta})=1.e^{i\theta}$ is a homomorphism with kernel being the set of positive reals.

By the Fundamental theorem of homomorphism we can say that $\mathbb{C}^*/P$ is isomorphic to $f(\mathbb{C}^*)=S^1$. 
where $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | |z|=1\}$.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is in any way different than B.S's way. i am just omitting maps and trying to see just as a quotient.

We see  $x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$ as $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$

Now, As  $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\in \mathbb{R}$ when we see $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$ modulo real numbers we would get  :

$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})\equiv (\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) \text { mod }\mathbb{R}$$

And then we have $|(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})|=\sqrt{(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})^2+(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})^2}=1$

So,for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $z=|z|(z')$ for $|z|\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|z'|=1$.

Thus $\mathbb{C}^*/P=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$